# got error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs

I want to show full object including comments(which is the array of objects) in the div upon one single command but i got error on the map function of comments.please help me out from this ....

```
 const fields2 = [

    {
        month: 30,
        unitrate: 2,
        budget: 6000,
        comments: [
            {
                id: 4500,
                rating: 11111111111,
                comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                author: "John Lemon",
                date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                rating: 22222222222,
                comment:
                    "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                author: "Paul McVites",
                date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
]
}
];


render() {

        return (
            <div>

                { fields2.map((ob,index)=>{ return (ob.month  +" " + ob.comments.map((ok,index)=>{ ok  }   )) }) }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: { fields2.map((ob,index)=>{ return (ob.month  +" " + JSON.stringify(ob.comments)) }) }

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below mentioned code

```
 { fields2.map((ob,index)=>{ return (ob.month  +" " + JSON.stringify(ob.comments,null,4)) }) }
```